# Confusion on the solution for Brezis Exercise 4.10

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-explanation, convex-analysis, lp-spaces

This is Exercise 4.10 on Brezis and I am having trouble understanding Brezis' solution for **part 3** of the problem:
[image]

**This is the part of the solution where I am lost:**

[image]

**My question is two-folds:** Why do we know that there exists a unique maximum for the given set above? I am trying to show that the function $f(x)u - j(u)-\frac{1}{n}|u|^p$ is strictly concave and approaches $-\infty$ as $|u| \to \infty$. However, I am skeptical about $f(x)u - j(u)-\frac{1}{n}|u|^p \to -\infty$ as $|u| \to \infty$. In particular, since we do not know the behavior of $j$, how can we conclude the value of the limit? My second questions, how do we know
$$
j(u(x)) + \frac{1}{n}|u(x)|^p - f(x)u(x) \leq j(0)
$$
implies $u \in L^p(\Omega)$ and $j(u) \in L^1(\Omega)$? I am trying to show this through integrating both sides, but this approach needs us to have $\int_\Omega f(x)u(x) \,dx < \infty$. This does not seem to be obvious to me. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=j'_+(0)$ denote the right derivative of $j$ at $0$, which exists by convexity. Then $j(u) \ge au+b$ for all real $u$, where $b=j(0)$.
(In other words, a convex function has a subgradient at every point on its graph. )
Therefore,
$$\Psi(u):=f(x)u-j(u)-\frac{1}{n}|u|^p \le [f(x)-a]u-b-\frac{1}{n}|u|^p \to -\infty \quad \text{as} \; |u| \to \infty \,,$$
because $p>1$. $\;$  Since  $\Psi$ is strictly concave, there is a unique $u=u(x)$ where its maximum is attained.

Next, from
$$
j(u(x)) + \frac{1}{n}|u(x)|^p - f(x)u(x) \leq j(0)=b \,,  \quad(*)
$$
we infer that for all $x$,
$$
  \frac{1}{n}|u(x)|^p \le [f(x)-a] \cdot  u(x)  \, \,,
$$
so
$$ |u(x)| ^{p-1} \le  n|f(x)-a|   \,.$$
Thus, if $\mu$ is the measure that $\Omega$ is equipped with, then
$$ \int_\Omega |u(x)|^p \, d\mu=\int_\Omega |u(x)|^{(p-1)p'} \, d\mu \le n^{p'}\int_\Omega |f(x)-a|^{p'}  \, d\mu <\infty \,,
$$ where we used finiteness of $\mu(\Omega)$ and the assumption  $f \in L^{p'}$ in the rightmost inequality. Hence   $u \in L^p$.

Observe that $(*)$ also yields
$$0 \le j(u(x))-au(x)-b \le |f(x)-a| \cdot |u(x)| \,.$$
Since $f-a \in L^{p'}$ and $u \in L^p$, Holder's inequality implies that $|f(x)-a| \cdot |u(x)| \in L^1$, so
$j \circ u-au-b \in L^1$ as well. Finally $u \in L^p$ so $u \in L^1$,
and the triangle inequality gives that $j \circ u \in L^1$.